# Want a smoother animation when resizing images javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-resizing

I have two images which are inside a container. The images are uploaded, so I won't know their sizes ahead of time. I used this function to resize the images to fit their container. The resizing works fine, but the animation is choppy. I was wondering if there was a way to make it look smoother.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  window.SurveyCreator = new SurveyCreator();
  setTimeout(function() {
    equalheight('.options-container');
  }, 1000);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  equalheight('.options-container');
});

equalheight = function(container) {
  var currentTallest = 0,
      currentRowStart = 0,
      rowDivs = new Array(),
      $el,
      topPosition = 0;

  $(container).each(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    $($el).height('auto')
    topPostion = $el.position().top;

    if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
      for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
        rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
      }
      rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
      currentRowStart = topPostion;
      currentTallest = $el.height();
      rowDivs.push($el);
    } else {
      rowDivs.push($el);
      currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
    }

    for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
      rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
    }
  });
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<div id="options-box" class="options-box">
  <div class="options-container">
    <img class="question-option" id="question-option-a">
  </div>
  <div class="options-container">
    <img class="question-option" id="question-option-b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.question-option {
    width: 100%;
}

.options-container {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #F2F1F5;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 1%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}

.options-box {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: You could use jQuery UIs `.animate('height')` function for this instead of the normal `.height()` function

Answer (score 0):

try adding a transition to the css of the container.

```
.options-container {
    transition: 1s;
}
```

you may want to add browser specific versions of "transition" as well:

```
.options-container {
    transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
}
```

also, to only animate height write "height 1s" instead of "1s".

Comment: Do you mean `transition`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered refactoring this to use .animate()? If you were to do that you could utilize VelocityJS which would make it smoother.